# How to upload video and display in HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to upload video and display in HTML page. Right now I did same for images that is working fine below.

How can i do same for videos?

My Code:-

```js
$('#addPhotosBtn').click(function() {
  $(this).parents().find('#addPhotosInput').click();
});

document.getElementById('addPhotosInput').onchange = e => {
  const file = e.target.files[0];
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  const li = ` <li> <img src=" ${url} ">
       <span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span>
   </li>`
  $('.photos-list ul').append(li);
};
```

```css
.photos-list ul,
.videos-list ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.photos-list ul li,
.videos-list ul li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  width: 19%;
  margin: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.photos-list ul li img,
.videos-list ul li img {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 110px;
}

.photos-list ul li span,
.videos-list ul li span {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  padding: 5px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.photos-list ul li span svg,
.videos-list ul li span svg {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <input type="file" class="d-none" id="addPhotosInput">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary" id="addPhotosBtn">Add Photos <i class="fa fa-camera"></i> </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="photos-list">
        <ul>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

ThankYou for your Efforts!

Comment: Please check may be help you https://jsfiddle.net/9pfjq6zr/2/
and added video extensions like mp4,wmv,webm etc in `validExtensions` variable

Comment: `validExtensions = ["mp4","webm","wmv"];` like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. I've added `accept` attributes on `<input type='file'>` which
   specifies a filter for what file types the user can pick from
   dialog:

   Images: `accept="image/png, image/gif, image/jpeg"`, Videos:
   `accept=" video/*"`
2. I've also added `<video>` element in JS code, a standard way to embed video in web pages.

   `<video controls="controls" src=" ${url} " type="video/mp4" width="400px" height="200px"></video>`

```js
$('#addPhotosBtn').click(function() {
  $(this).parents().find('#addPhotosInput').click();
});

document.getElementById('addPhotosInput').onchange = e => {
  const file = e.target.files[0];
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  const li = ` <li> <img src=" ${url} ">
   <span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span>
   </li>`
  $('.photos-list ul').append(li);
};

$('#addVideosBtn').click(function() {
  $(this).parents().find('#addVideosInput').click();
});

document.getElementById('addVideosInput').onchange = e => {
  const file = e.target.files[0];
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  const li = ` <li> <video controls="controls" src=" ${url} " type="video/mp4" width="400px" height="200px"></video>
       <span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span>
   </li>`
  $('.video-list ul').append(li);
};
```

```css
.photos-list ul,
.videos-list ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.photos-list ul li,
.videos-list ul li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  width: 19%;
  margin: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.photos-list ul li img,
.videos-list ul li img {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 110px;
}

.photos-list ul li span,
.videos-list ul li span {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  padding: 5px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.photos-list ul li span svg,
.videos-list ul li span svg {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">

  <!-- Photos -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <input type="file" class="d-none" id="addPhotosInput" accept="image/png, image/gif, image/jpeg">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary" id="addPhotosBtn">Add Photos <i class="fa fa-camera"></i> </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="photos-list">
        <ul>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
<!-- Video -->

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <input type="file" class="d-none" id="addVideosInput" accept=" video/*">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary" id="addVideosBtn">Add Videos <i class="fa fa-camera"></i> </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="video-list">
        <ul>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

References: [html5-video](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/html-tutorial/html5-video.php), [`<input>` accept](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_accept.asp#:%7E:text=The%20accept%20attribute%20specifies%20a,be%20validated%20on%20the%20server.)